# What is the best way to translate 中？?

Tags: translation, suffixes

Although this seems to be more of an English question, it deals with Japanese usage, so I would like some help here.

We know the kanji 中; I am talking about when this is used for processes that are happening. For example 回収中、実行中、動作中...
What would be a correct way to translate this into English? Sometimes I use "In" as in "In Operation", sometimes I use the "ing" as in "Collecting", etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's not really any single answer, it'll depend on whatever term that includes it you're trying to translate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Language is not a science, nor is translation.  There should be no such thing as the single best translation for 「～～中{ちゅう}」.

Whatever sounds best for the context in the ***target language*** would be the best.

> in, within, during, while, in the middle of, in the course of, under (as in "under investigation" = 「調査中{ちょうさちゅう}」), etc.

Thus, no matter what word comes before the 「中」 in the original Japanese, there should usually be one or two word/phrase choices that sound natural in English.